# Change indentation unit for CodeMirror Python

Tags: javascript, python, codemirror

I don't see a way to change indentation unit to two-space or best, make it automatically detect the unit: http://codemirror.net/mode/python/index.html

[image]

As you can see, the `if` showed read since it got `cm-error` class. It has two-space indent. But the `print` is fine. Although this code block works fine.

So:

1. Is there a way to make the code using two-space indentation?
2. Is it possible to make automatic indentation unit?

I tried to play around with http://codemirror.net/mode/python/python.js and cannot come up with any conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`indentUnit`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_indentUnit) option. There's no auto-detection in the library, but you might be able to write a little script that finds the first line that's indented more than the one above it, and take the difference as a likely guess.